# Win10 External USB HDD partition there, but no drive in Explorer

Tags: external-hard-drive, ntfs

Win10 External USB HDD partition there, but no drive in Explorer. External USB Toshiba drive. How did I regain access to the files on that drive? Here's what DiskPart shows me:

```
Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.18362.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: T420
DISKPART> list disk
  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          476 GB      0 B
  Disk 1    Online          447 GB      0 B
  Disk 2    Online          119 GB      0 B
  Disk 3    Online         1863 GB  1024 KB

DISKPART> sel disk 3
Disk 3 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list part
  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary           1863 GB    31 KB

DISKPART> list vol
  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     D   SSD-SATA     NTFS   Partition    476 GB  Healthy
  Volume 1         System Rese  NTFS   Partition    579 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 2     C   MMC-SATA     NTFS   Partition    292 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 3     F   CARD-128     FAT32  Removable    119 GB  Healthy
```

Comment: Can you include information from `detail part`?

Comment: Once I get home tonight, yes.

Comment: FAT32 is generally for volumes of 32GB or less, It is used and can work above that size (and even up to 8TB or so) but by design it isn't meant to. Windows 10 has limited this more by removing the option from disk manager for drives bigger than 32GB. If you have no need to use FAT32 as the format then you could try using NTFS or exFAT which may resolve the issue. 

EDIT: Have just re-read, be aware that formatting will likely delete your files, so I suppose this doesn't actually help, but if you copied off the files as in the answer from Sudo, formatting may show the drive in explorer.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to gain access to the files, then follow the steps,

1. First, identify which letter has been assigned to which volume.
2. So if you want to access the files in the volume whose name is "SSD-SATA", then locate the letter of that volume; which is D:\ in your case.
3. Then open up a Command Prompt and run `cd D:\`
4. This will allow you to work on that directory.Now you type `dir` to list all files in the directory.
5. If you want to copy all files in the drive then type the following in cmd, `copy /-Y * yourmainharddriveletter\restoredfiles`

The command copies everything inside the drive to a folder in your computer hard drive called "Restored Files" I don't know your Computer Hard-drive path, so if you don't know the path of your computer hard drive, open File explorer you should find it there!

Comment: Nope. C: (Disk 1), D: (Disk 0) and F:(Disk 2) are not the problem. Problem is Disk 3.

Comment: @K7AAY But the volumes under disk 3 aren't mounting, right?